# Calculating Diagonal Elements of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ From R Output

Tags: r, regression, self-study

> With $X$ being the design matrix, calculate the diagonal elements of the matrix $(X^TX)^{-1}$ using only the R output.

[image]

I found the diagonal elements to be $$\frac{1}{n SSX} \bigg[n,\sum X_{i1}^2, \sum X_{i2}^2 \bigg]$$ but I don´t see any way of calculating this based on the R output.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Find the formula for the standard errors of the coefficient estimators.  Notice also that these standard errors are given to you in the output.

Comment: So $Var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$ But I don't see how to extract diagonal elements this way? Also, isn't $\hat{\beta}$ a $px1$ matrix, while $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is an $nxn$ matrix?

Comment: It's a $p \times p$ matrix

Comment: Still doesen´t make much sense if the left hand side is a $px1$ matrix and the right hand side a $pxp$ matrix.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).

Comment: Okay, so then the diagonal elements of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ are given by $\frac{Var(\beta_i)}{\sigma^2}$ ?